# Downgrading PHP 5.4 to 5.3 on CentOS 6.5?

Tags: php, linux, centos, downgrade

I need a big help. Regarding register_globals deprecated and removed as of PHP 5.4.0, I need to downgrade PHP to 5.3 version on CentOS ver. 6.5 server. Please tell me step by step how to do it. I have Scalable Cloud Hosting (VPS) with PHP 5.4.27 and Apache 2.2.15 installed on it.

Comment: Well, you need to find a CentOS repository that still offers that old version. Then you can switch between versions. But honestly: doesn't it make more sense to modify your application? There is a reason why `register_globals` has been deprecated for ages: it is a _huge_ security issue.

Comment: You're far better off fixing the register_globals issue in the PHP script you're running, or replacing it with a newer version, rather than downgrading to an older less secure version of PHP that's not going to be supported for much longer.

Comment: How will I fix the register_globals issue in my PHP script? Please give me detailed instructions.

Comment: @StiMis075 I have same issue.You have found any solution help me.